# SQL Bike Color example

Tags: sql, distinct

I have an SQL text book example but it seems highly complex. 
The table has columns:

`Bike_ID` (primary key), `Color_Wheel`, `Color_Frame`, `Color_Cables`, `Color_Gearbox`, `Color_Brakes`, `Color_Lamps`, `Color_Paddle`, `Color_Chain`, `Color_Saddle`, and others...

And I only want to select the rows where at least 6 of the colors are different. So at least 6 of the values in the 9 color columns are supposed to be different.

It seems this is highly complex in SQL.  In Matlab or Java it is trivial to use `setdiff()` or `intersect()` and then count the results. I thought it might be a one liner in SQL - can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

To find bikes with at least 6 different colors, do a `UNION ALL` with a select for each part color. Do a `GROUP BY` where you check the number of different colors in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select * from tablename
where Bike_ID in
(
    select Bike_ID
    (
    select Bike_ID, Color_Wheel as color from tablename
    union all
    select Bike_ID, Color_Frame as color from tablename
    ...
    union all
    select Bike_ID, Color_Saddle as color from tablename
    )
    group by Bike_ID
    having count(distinct color) >= 6
)
```

Comment: You can also do just `UNION`, and check `count(*) => 6`.